# NodeJs gaming screen recorder

Tags: node.js, opengl, directx, electron

I use electronJs and have developed a small screen recorder. Now I had the idea that I could create ingame videos as well.

The only problem is that the window of the games remain black.
I'm assuming that somehow I need to get access to DirectX, OpenGL ... to do this.

But how is this possible, or is there another way to record with Nodejs, ingame videos?

Thanks